# Sharepoint 2013 App catalog

Tags: sharepoint, admin

In the sharepoint 2013,i upload the app in the app catalog but now it is not working...after the app catalog page ,apps for sharepoint is not showing.what i have to do now?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a new app or another version. If it is another version of the app make sure you have changed the version number before reuploading the app.